# Show the most current dateusing MAX Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

Table covidDeaths

```
Location        Date                    total_cases  total_deaths             
_______________________________________________________________________
United States   2020-01-22 00:00:00.000            1    NULL
United States   2020-01-23 00:00:00.000            1    0
United States   2020-01-24 00:00:00.000            2    1
United States   2020-01-25 00:00:00.000            2    0
United States   2020-01-26 00:00:00.000            5    3
United States   2021-11-11 00:00:00.000     46851529    58626
United States   2021-11-12 00:00:00.000     46991304    139775
United States   2021-11-13 00:00:00.000     47050502    59198
United States   2021-11-14 00:00:00.000     47074080    23578
```

I'm running into a problem that is leaving me a bit frustrated. I am looking for the total_cases and total_deaths using the most current date where the location is the United States in a table named covidDeaths. I know you can use the `Max()` function to find the most current date on file so I have tried

```
SELECT MAX(date) AS "Current Date", total_deaths, total_cases 
FROM covidDeaths
WHERE location = 'United States'
GROUP BY total_cases, total_deaths;
```

I want it to output a single row like this.

```
_______________________________________
|Current Date|Total_Deaths|Total_Cases|
|____________|____________|___________|
|2021-11-14  |763092      |47074080   |
|____________|____________|___________|
```

Instead, I'm getting

```
_______________________________________
|Current Date|Total_Deaths|Total_Cases|
|____________|____________|___________|
|2020-01-23  |Null        |1          |
|____________|____________|___________|
|2020-01-24  |Null        |2          |
|____________|____________|___________|
```

and so on until it reaches the max (date).

I am using SQL Server 2019.
I'm hoping someone can explain to me what I am doing wrong and why it's outputting multiple dates instead of just the most current.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: As already said ^^^ we need to see your sample data.

Comment: Is your "date" coumn an actual date, or string?

Comment: @CriticalError Yes date is a datetime datatype

Comment: @KenWhite thank you for the correction I just edited it, I hope  its considered a reproducible table.

Comment: @EduardoGamboa-Cruz did the answer below help you?

Comment: @DaleK it got the output I needed but I was still wondering why my query shows me all the dates instead of just the most current date.  When I write SELECT Max(date) FROM covidDeaths; it will show me the most current date why does that not with my query. If you could explain that would be amazing or just a site where I can learn this more in depth.

Comment: Ask that question of Tim below his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `TOP` query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES date AS [Current Date], total_deaths, total_cases
FROM covidDeaths
WHERE location = 'United States'
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

I am using `WITH TIES` here in case there might be more than one record having the most recent date.  If not, or you don't care about ties, then you may simply use `TOP 1` instead.

Note: I see no reason to be using `GROUP BY` here, as your current query does not select any aggregates.

Comment: I got the output I needed but I was still wondering why my query shows me all the dates instead of just the most current date. When I write SELECT Max(date) FROM covidDeaths; it will show me the most current date why does that not happen with my query. If you could explain that would be amazing or just a site where I can learn this more in depth.

Comment: You asked for the max date for each pair of deaths/cases.  This isn't the same thing as asking for the deaths/cases corresponding to the max date across the entire table.

Comment: @Eduardo Because your current query asks for the highest date _for each combination_ of deaths and cases.